# React freezes when trying to add million elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making an app with tree in which every item has 10^depth child elements (max depth is 5). It all goes ok, but more deeper I open tree branches, the more time it takes to render it. On the 5th level it even can freeze.

Here is my code:

```
      class TreeNode extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {
              expanded: false,
              depth: this.props.parentDepth + 1
          }
          this.treeExpand = this.treeExpand.bind(this);
      }

      treeExpand() {
          if (this.state.depth <= 5) {
              this.setState({
                  expanded: !this.state.expanded
              });
          }
      }

      prepareNodes(){
        if (this.state.expanded) {
            var tree = [];
            for (var i = 1; i < Math.pow(10, this.props.parentDepth + 1) + 1; i++) {
                tree.push(<TreeNode parentDepth={this.state.depth} selfNum={i} parentStack={this.props.parentStack+' > '+this.props.selfNum} />);
            }
            return <ul>{tree}</ul>;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
      }


      render() {
          return (
              <li key={this.props.parentStack+'-'+this.props.selfNum}>
                <span onClick={this.treeExpand}>
                   {(this.state.expanded ? '[-]' : '[+]')}
                   {this.props.selfNum}
                   ({this.props.parentStack})
                 </span>
                   {this.prepareNodes()}
                 </li>
          );
      }
  }

  class TreeSection extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props)
      }


      render() {
          var tree = [];
          for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
              tree.push(<TreeNode parentDepth={1} selfNum={i} parentStack={'root'}/>);
          }
          return (
              <ul>
                {tree}
              </ul>
          );
      }
  }


  ReactDOM.render(
      <TreeSection />,
      document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

[Image: expanded tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSCtF.png)

I think that this may be caused by too big array returned by prepareNodes() function. How can it be fixed? I'm new to React.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more specifics, I can say with that many nodes the object definitely should be broken up into logical segments. If the data is a large collection, it needs to be paginated by your server - there is only so much your browser (and machine) can handle. With the info provided, I think this is not a front-end issue, but rather how your data is provided to your front-end.

Comment: Data is generated on client. Also browser itself renders 1000000 elements just fine, the issue must be with memory overflow.